# openlayers bing hide label

Tags: javascript, openlayers, bing-maps

I use Openlayers 2 with one Bing layer. But I would like to hide the labels (city, streets...) 
I found something about in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427602.aspx
How I use this property with openlayer.

```
var road = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
        key: apiKey,
        type: "Road",
        // custom metadata parameter to request the new map style - only useful
        // before May 1st, 2011
        metadataParams: { mapVersion: "v1" },
    });
```

Thanks
Christophe

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to do that in OpenLayers. This can only be done in the Bing Maps V8 map control. Here is the code to do this in V8:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    allowHidingRoadLabels: true,
    labelOverlay: Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.hidden
});
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much